# Black and white sci-fi film from the late '90s or early 2000s about a UFO that crashed near a small town

Tags: story-identification, movie

I was laying on the couch about 10-15 years ago and a black and white movie came on, but it was obvious it was newly made because it was in high definition and extremely clear.

The premise was about a small town and just outside of that town there was a mountain range.  Something crashed in the mountain range and I seem to recall either the local police or some teens drove out and found a crashed flying saucer.   Something like a blob or ooze escaped from the saucer and made its way back into town.

From there I don't remember anything.  I've been googling for a good five years off and on now trying to find "black and white movie made in early 2000s or late 1990s" and can't seem to find it.  It was pretty basic and seemingly low budget, but it was awesome.

Comment: There is a movie which is partially in black and white made in 2007 called Aaah! Zombies!! IMBD link: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1027762/

Comment: Do you remember the setting of the movie?  Was it modern times, retro (1950's, for example).  Think about the cars used, that sort of thing.  It would help narrow the search.

Answer (score 3):

Are you remembering **The Lost Skeleton of Cadavra**?

Info from the intro of [the movie's Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Skeleton_of_Cadavra) (emphasis mine):

> **2001 American independent science-fiction parody film** directed by
> Larry Blamire. The film is a spoof of B movies released during the
> 1950s. The film was videotaped on a budget of less than US$100,000,
> and was **converted to black-and-white** film in post-production.

[image: The Lost Skeleton of Cadavra cover]

Elements of the plot match your description (and my memory, again emphasis mine):

> In 1961, scientist Dr. Paul Armstrong (Larry Blamire) and his wife
> Betty (Fay Masterson) **drive into the mountains**. Dr. Armstrong is
> searching for a meteorite that has fallen in the nearby woods,
> suspected to contain the rare element atmosphereum. Another scientist
> in the area, Dr. Roger Fleming (Brian Howe) questions Ranger Brad (Dan
> Conroy) about Cadavra Cave, a site rumored to contain a "Lost
> Skeleton".
>
> That evening, both the Armstrongs and Dr. Fleming observe another
> falling meteor. A short time later a farmer (Robert Deveau),
> encountered by the Armstrongs on their way to the cabin, is mutilated
> by a mysterious beast. The **second meteorite is actually a spaceship
> carrying two aliens**. Kro-Bar (Andrew Parks) and Lattis (Susan
> McConnell) are from the planet Marva and are now stranded on Earth, in
> need of the element atmosphereum to repair their powerless ship. The
> ship's pet mutant (Darren Reed) escapes from its cage while they are
> distracted.